# How do I make a date representation ('1/1/2014') from = 3-1-2014 5:50:46, Function loadDatabaseFromSheet()

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I am new to Appsript Script.Db

We have a spreadsheet whit about 300 row's of date in the first column date : 3-1-2014 5:50:46.
When we do a function loadDatabaseFromSheet() we get the error date Timestamp is not a number.

> ScriptDB cannot store Date objects directly; instead, you must store a representation of the >date and reconstruct it later. If you don't intend to search based on dates, then you can >store the numeric timestamp from the Date object like this:

```
var date = new Date('1/1/2014');
var item = {
  timestamp: date.getTime();
}
var record = db.save(item);
```

Do we have change all the date by hand in a proper way from 3-1-2014 5:50:46 to '3/1/2014'?

Hope that there is a better way to get this done?

// How and where can i make a representation: ('1/1/2014');  I hope i don't have to change 
// all the date's in the spreadsheet by hand ?My spreadsheet has 300 Row's, first collumn =

Comment: are the dates in your spreadsheet real dates ? meaning you get a calendar UI when you double click them ? if so why using a string representation instead of the date object itself ? and if not, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

The script DB cannot save Date datatype by default, so what you need to do is covert it to its time representation and save it to DB as the above info suggests.

As for your question regarding the need to change date format, it will not be necessary just do a (new Date(value)).getTime() at the time of saving to the DB. Where value represents the datetime in the first column.